# Spring datasource + JPA + Hibernate +c3p0 + ehCache

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, c3p0

I want to connect to my MySQL database using the folliowing libraries:

- spring: because my webapp use the spring-mvc framework
- hibernate (JPA): because it is a standard
- c3p0: for performance
- ehCache: for performance

Here is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="dao,service" />

    <!-- Configuration du transaction manager -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="entity" />

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <!-- used for debug -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- EhCache -->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">classpath:ehcache.xml</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                <!-- configuration pool via c3p0, see https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop> <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">5</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</prop> <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</prop> <prop key="hibernate.checkoutTimeout">1000</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod">30</prop> <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configuration de la BDD -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

I dont get any error but I'm not sure that c3p0 and ehCache are working :/

Comment: What makes you think that those compoments are not working? Also you should check out `HikariCP` for better connection pool performance than c3p0

Comment: Thanks, when I was student, the teacher teachs us connection pool using c3p0. But I agree, it looks deprecated in comparison with HikariCP

Comment: It does seem that HikariCP is very very fast!

Comment: I'll try to configure it with HikariCP

Comment: Sounds like a good choice!!

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late, but anyway.

One mistake in your XML is that you tried to configure both datasource and `hibernate.c3p0` in `entityManagerFactory` bean. When you do this way, hibernate will not take into account any `hibernate.c3p0` properties (because it will not instantiate `DataSource` in that case).

So, if you set datasource to EntityManagerFactory (or SessionFactory), you should consider configuring connection-pooling at Datasource side, like this (C3P0):

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true" />
    <property name="user" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="2"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000"/>
</bean>
```

or any other way you like.

This behaviour is barely documented in Spring documentation, here is [what I have found](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/AbstractSessionFactoryBean.html#setDataSource-javax.sql.DataSource-).

For ComboPooledDataSource, see [c3p0 documentation](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)

As related to hibernate caching, it should work properly.